# refresh the listview by clicking an item in Navigation drawer - Android

Tags: android, listview, android-fragments, android-intent, navigation-drawer

When ever I click an item from Navigation Drawer , it will pass a String to MainActivity and then ListView Adapter gets refreshed. But I don't know how to do this

without everytime calling `startActivity(new Intent(getActivity(),MAinActivity.class))`

**Main Activity**

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements ResultCallBack {
Toolbar toolbar;
recyclerAdapter adap;
PlaceHolderFragment taskFragment;
ListView listView;
urlGiver getUrlGiver;
String message;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    //forceShowActionBarOverflowMenu();
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.app_bar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    NavDrawerFragment drawerFragment = (NavDrawerFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frg_nav_drawer);
    drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.frg_nav_drawer, (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), toolbar);
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);

    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        taskFragment = new PlaceHolderFragment();
        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(taskFragment, "fragment").commit();

    } else {

        taskFragment = (PlaceHolderFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("fragment");

    }

    Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
    if (bundle != null) {
        message = bundle.getString("message");
    } else {
        message = "http://kwtoffers.com/?feed=rss2";
    }

    taskFragment.startTask(message);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    int id = item.getItemId();

    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        Toast.makeText(this, "ok clicked settings", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (id == R.id.navigate) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this, SubActivity.class));
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}


@Override
public void onPreExecute() {

}


@Override
public void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result) {
    try {
        listView.setAdapter(new myAdapter(result, this));

        // L.m("" + result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        L.m("exception from post execute" + e);
    }
    // L.m("" + result);
}


public static class PlaceHolderFragment extends Fragment {
    bbcWeather downloadTask;
    ResultCallBack callBack = null;
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> r;
    String url;

    public PlaceHolderFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }


    @Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        callBack = (ResultCallBack) activity;
        if (downloadTask != null) {
            downloadTask.onAttach(callBack);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        callBack = null;
        if (downloadTask != null) {
            downloadTask.onDetach();
        }
    }

    public void startTask(String url) {
        if (downloadTask != null) {
            downloadTask.cancel(true);
        } else {
            downloadTask = new bbcWeather(callBack);
            this.url = url;
            downloadTask.url = url;
            downloadTask.execute();
        }
    }


}

static HashMap<String, Bitmap> images = null;

public static class bbcWeather extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> {
    ResultCallBack callBack = null;

    public String url;
    urlGiver urlgiver;


    public bbcWeather(ResultCallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;
    }

    public void onAttach(ResultCallBack callBack) {
        this.callBack = callBack;

    }

    public void onDetach() {
        callBack = null;
    }

    HashMap<String, String> cMap = null;

    @Override
    protected ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> doInBackground(Void... params) {
        if (url == null)
            url = "http://kwtoffers.com/?feed=rss2";


        L.m(url + "");

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = null;
        try {
            URL javURL = new URL(url);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) javURL.openConnection();
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
            InputStream inputStream = connection.getInputStream();
            result = new ArrayList<>();
            result = processXML(inputStream, url);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            L.m("exception from http url -> " + e);
        }
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> hashMaps) {
        if (callBack != null) {
            callBack.onPostExecute(hashMaps);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        if (callBack != null) {
            callBack.onPreExecute();
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> processXML(InputStream inputStream, String url) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory documentBuilderFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder documentBuilder = documentBuilderFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document xmlDocument = documentBuilder.parse(inputStream);
        Element rootElement = xmlDocument.getDocumentElement();
        NodeList itemList = rootElement.getElementsByTagName("item");
        Node currentItem = null;
        NodeList itemChildren = null;
        Node childItem = null;


        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> results = new ArrayList<>();
        HashMap<String, String> currentMap = null;


        for (int i = 0; i < itemList.getLength(); i++) {

            currentItem = itemList.item(i);
            itemChildren = currentItem.getChildNodes();
            currentMap = new HashMap<>();
            cMap = new HashMap<>();
            for (int j = 0; j < itemChildren.getLength(); j++) {
                childItem = itemChildren.item(j);

                if (childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("title")) {
                    //L.m("" + childItem.getTextContent());
                    currentMap.put("title", childItem.getTextContent());
                }
                if (childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("pubDate")) {
                    //L.m("" + childItem.getTextContent());
                    currentMap.put("pubDate", childItem.getTextContent());
                }

                if (childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("dc:creator")) {
                    //L.m("" + childItem.getTextContent());
                    currentMap.put("dc:creator", childItem.getTextContent());
                }
                if (childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("description")) {
                    String str = childItem.getTextContent();
                    str += "\n";
                    if (url.equals("http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/285787/3dayforecast.rss")) {
                        str = " " + str.replace(",", "\n\n");
                        currentMap.put("description", str);
                    } else {
                        currentMap.put("description", str);
                    }

                }
                if (childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("link")) {
                    currentMap.put("description_link", childItem.getTextContent());
                }


                if (childItem.getNodeName().equalsIgnoreCase("content:encoded")) {
                    //L.m("" + childItem.getTextContent());
                    String t = childItem.getTextContent();
                    org.jsoup.nodes.Document document = Jsoup.parse(t);
                    String output = document.select("img").attr("src");
                    //String output = String.valueOf(document.getElementsByTag("img"));
                    L.m("" + output);
                    currentMap.put("imageURL", output);

                }


            }

            results.add(currentMap);
        }


        return results;
    }
}
```

}

**ListView's Adapter**

```
class myAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
public static Bitmap bitmap;
public static HashMap<String, Bitmap> images;

public void setImages(HashMap<String, Bitmap> images) {
    this.images = images;

}


ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataSource = new ArrayList<>();
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public myAdapter(ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> dataSource, Context context) {
    this.dataSource = dataSource;
    this.context = context;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}

@Override
public int getCount() { // to retrieve total elements in a result arraylist
    return dataSource.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return dataSource.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    //      this will be used to add data to our custom_row.xml
    View row = convertView;
    Myholder holder = null;
    if (row == null) {
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_row, parent, false);
        holder = new Myholder(row);
        row.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (Myholder) row.getTag();
    }

    final HashMap<String, String> currentItem = dataSource.get(position);
    holder.title.setText(currentItem.get("title"));
    holder.pubdate.setText(currentItem.get("pubDate"));

    holder.description.setText(currentItem.get("description"));
    holder.description.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity((Activity) context, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentItem.get("description_link"))), Bundle.EMPTY);
        }
    });
    holder.author.setText(currentItem.get("dc:creator"));
    try {
        Picasso.with(context).load(currentItem.get("imageURL")).into(holder.image);
        holder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("content://media/external/images/media/16")));
                startActivity((Activity) context, new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(currentItem.get("imageURL"))), Bundle.EMPTY);
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        L.m("" + e);
    }
    return row;
}

public static void setImageFromURL(Bitmap bmp) {
    bitmap = bmp;
}

public Bitmap getImageFromURL() {
    return bitmap;
}
```

}

**Navigation Drawer Fragment**

```
public class NavDrawerFragment extends Fragment implements recyclerAdapter.clicker {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
recyclerAdapter.MyViewHolder obj;
boolean t;
ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
private View ContainerView;
DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
private boolean learnt, fromSavedInstanceState;
public static final String PREF_FILE_NAME = "myFile", KEY_USER_LEARNT = "user_learnt";
private recyclerAdapter adap;

public NavDrawerFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

public static List<information> ok() {
    List<information> list = new ArrayList<>();
    // int[] images = {R.mipmap.ic_action_ads,R.mipmap.ic_action_news,R.mipmap.ic_action_weather};
    int[] images = {R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher, R.mipmap.ic_launcher};
    String[] title = {"Today's Promotion", "Today's News", "3 Days Weather-forecast", "Important Contacts"};

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        information current = new information();
        current.titleID = title[i];
        current.ImageID = images[i];
        list.add(current);
    }
    return list;
}


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    learnt = Boolean.valueOf(readfromPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNT, "false"));
    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        fromSavedInstanceState = true;
    }

}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View layout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_nav_drawer, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) layout.findViewById(R.id.recycler_drawer_list);
    this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    adap = new recyclerAdapter(getActivity(), ok());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adap);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    adap.setClicker(this);
    return layout;
}


public void setUp(int fragmentID, final DrawerLayout drawerLayout, Toolbar toolbar) {
    ContainerView = getActivity().findViewById(R.id.frg_nav_drawer);
    this.drawerLayout = drawerLayout;
    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(getActivity(), drawerLayout, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close) {
        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);
            if (!learnt) {
                learnt = true;
                saveToPreference(getActivity(), KEY_USER_LEARNT, learnt + "true");
            }
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();

        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
            getActivity().invalidateOptionsMenu();
        }

    };


    if (!learnt && !fromSavedInstanceState) {
        //drawerLayout.openDrawer(ContainerView);
    }
    this.drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();


}


public static void saveToPreference(Context context, String PreferenceName, String PreferenceValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putString(PreferenceName, PreferenceValue);
    editor.apply();

}

public static String readfromPreference(Context context, String PreferenceName, String DefaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return DefaultValue;
}


@Override
public void itemClicked(View v, int position) {
    urlGiver setURL = new urlGiver();
    String message;
    Intent intent;
    drawerLayout.closeDrawer(ContainerView);
    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            message = "http://kwtoffers.com/?feed=rss2";
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
            break;
        case 1:
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            message = "http://www.arabtimesonline.com/DesktopModules/DNNArticle/DNNArticleRSS.aspx?moduleid=414&tabid=69&categoryid=50";
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
            break;
        case 2:
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), MainActivity.class);
            message = "http://open.live.bbc.co.uk/weather/feeds/en/285787/3dayforecast.rss";
            intent.putExtra("message", message);
            startActivity(intent);
            getActivity().finish();
            break;
        case 3:
            intent = new Intent(getActivity(), SubActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
    }
}
```

}